# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input at JSON.parse

Tags: javascript, json, cross-origin-read-blocking

I am trying to load data from JSON to my website. Everything worked correctly for some time, but tonight I suddenly I started receiving the following error. (it works on localhost so far)

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at FileReader.<anonymous>
```

Javascript calling the JSON is following:

```
function readJSON(path) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', path, true);
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';
    xhr.onload = function(e) { 
        if (this.status == 200) {
            var file = new File([this.response], 'temp');
            var fileReader = new FileReader();
            fileReader.addEventListener('load', function(){
                // do stuff with fileReader.result
                var volant = JSON.parse(fileReader.result);
                // console.log(volant);   
            });
            fileReader.readAsText(file);
        } 
    }
    xhr.send();
}

readJSON('https://volant.inexsda.cz/v1/workcamps.json');
```

I need to read data from the JSON, but now I cannot anymore. Can someone help please?

EDIT: Everything works correctly on Safari. The issue is happening in Chrome.

Comment: Have you already checked the content you received from the HttpRequest? Please do so by adding a `console.log(fileReader.result)`. Post that result and check it yourself for correctness.

Comment: Are you sure the response type is a 'blob'? Blob is an object containing the binary data.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseType

Comment: console.log(fileReader.result) is empty

Comment: Not sure about the 'blob'. The whole "funny" issue is that code worked few hours ago and I did no changes in it. Plus it works in Safari and Firefox. Only Chrome is doing this :(

Comment: console.log(fileReader.result) is showing the content of JSON file in Safari (in Chrome it is empty)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @abestrad pointed out, `xhr.responseType = 'blob';` is a possible issue and should be `json` as outlined [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseType).

UPDATE:
Try the following, which is working for me in chrome from same domain:

```
function readJSON(path) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', path, true);
    xhr.responseType = 'json';
    xhr.onreadystatechange  = function(e) { 
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            if (this.status == 200) {
                console.log(this.response);
            } 
        }
    }
    xhr.send();
}

readJSON('https://volant.inexsda.cz/v1/workcamps.json');
```

Comment: Okay. I changed it, but now fileReader.result is null

Comment: @JakubŠnorbert, what does the network tab say when you fire off the request? There may be something in the headers of the response that could give more information.

Comment: Request URL: https://volant.inexsda.cz/v1/workcamps.json?page=1
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 83.167.225.248:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: authorization,x-goog-authuser
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Allow: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE
Provisional headers are shown
Origin: http://localhost:8888
Referer: http://localhost:8888/aktivity/workcampy/kratkodobe-workcampy/
page:1

Comment: You're not making cross-domain calls, are you?

Comment: Running on a localhost with exception for cross-domain call

Comment: So you get the object with data in fileReader.result?

Comment: No filereader is needed when you use responsetype as json. It's parsed as json when loaded. See my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried your code but console.log(this.response) is null for me :(

Comment: I added the ready state in there, just to be safe. I'm getting the feeling that there's something else going on that's causing your issue.

Comment: Your code works for me in Safari and Firefox, but Chrome is still not working. I will try to reinstall the browser and its addons tomorrow. Thx so far for help.

Comment: Last suggestion is to use onreadystatechange rather than onload. Example updated.

Comment: I couldn't sleep and I uninstalled completely Chrome and installed it again. Now everything works. Very weird thing as it was probably issue of my browser only. But thanks all for help.